# Why the `insert to TsFileProcessor` error happened in cluster version of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Under what circumstances will this `insert to TsFileProcessor` error be reported in Apache IoTDB? The complete error message is `[pool-20-IoTDB-IoTConsensusRPC-Processor-10] ERROR o.a.i.d.e.s.DataRegion:1134 - insert to TsFileProcessor error, org.apache.iotdb.db.exception.WriteProcessRejectException: System rejected over 11030ms`. I set 1 ConfigNode and 2 DataNode, and is currently running IoTDB on a single server.